# Обращение к структуре ProcessStartupInformation через wmi в C++

Tags: c++, wmi

Пытаюсь разобраться с wmi, использую последний снипет из статьи
[Calling a Provider Method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wmisdk/example--calling-a-provider-method)
Не могу понять как указать ProcessStartupInformation для Win32_Process.Create на примере этой статьи и вообще как обратится к структуре ProcessStartupInformation в данном коде?

```
#define _WIN32_DCOM
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <comdef.h>
#include <Wbemidl.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "wbemuuid.lib")

int main(int iArgCnt, char ** argv)
{
    HRESULT hres;

    // Step 1: --------------------------------------------------
    // Initialize COM. ------------------------------------------

    hres =  CoInitializeEx(0, COINIT_MULTITHREADED); 
    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        cout << "Failed to initialize COM library. Error code = 0x" 
             << hex << hres << endl;
        return 1;                  // Program has failed.
    }

    // Step 2: --------------------------------------------------
    // Set general COM security levels --------------------------

    hres =  CoInitializeSecurity(
        NULL, 
        -1,                          // COM negotiates service
        NULL,                        // Authentication services
        NULL,                        // Reserved
        RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_DEFAULT,   // Default authentication 
        RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE, // Default Impersonation
        NULL,                        // Authentication info
        EOAC_NONE,                   // Additional capabilities 
        NULL                         // Reserved
        );


    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        cout << "Failed to initialize security. Error code = 0x" 
             << hex << hres << endl;
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;                      // Program has failed.
    }

    // Step 3: ---------------------------------------------------
    // Obtain the initial locator to WMI -------------------------

    IWbemLocator *pLoc = NULL;

    hres = CoCreateInstance(
        CLSID_WbemLocator,
        0, 
        CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, 
        IID_IWbemLocator, (LPVOID *) &pLoc);

    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        cout << "Failed to create IWbemLocator object. "
             << "Err code = 0x"
             << hex << hres << endl;
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;                 // Program has failed.
    }

    // Step 4: ---------------------------------------------------
    // Connect to WMI through the IWbemLocator::ConnectServer method

    IWbemServices *pSvc = NULL;

    // Connect to the local root\cimv2 namespace
    // and obtain pointer pSvc to make IWbemServices calls.
    hres = pLoc->ConnectServer(
        _bstr_t(L"ROOT\\CIMV2"), 
        NULL,
        NULL, 
        0, 
        NULL, 
        0, 
        0, 
        &pSvc
    );

    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        cout << "Could not connect. Error code = 0x" 
             << hex << hres << endl;
        pLoc->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;                // Program has failed.
    }

    cout << "Connected to ROOT\\CIMV2 WMI namespace" << endl;


    // Step 5: --------------------------------------------------
    // Set security levels for the proxy ------------------------

    hres = CoSetProxyBlanket(
        pSvc,                        // Indicates the proxy to set
        RPC_C_AUTHN_WINNT,           // RPC_C_AUTHN_xxx 
        RPC_C_AUTHZ_NONE,            // RPC_C_AUTHZ_xxx 
        NULL,                        // Server principal name 
        RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_CALL,      // RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_xxx 
        RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE, // RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_xxx
        NULL,                        // client identity
        EOAC_NONE                    // proxy capabilities 
    );

    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        cout << "Could not set proxy blanket. Error code = 0x" 
             << hex << hres << endl;
        pSvc->Release();
        pLoc->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;               // Program has failed.
    }

    // Step 6: --------------------------------------------------
    // Use the IWbemServices pointer to make requests of WMI ----

    // set up to call the Win32_Process::Create method
    BSTR MethodName = SysAllocString(L"Create");
    BSTR ClassName = SysAllocString(L"Win32_Process");

    IWbemClassObject* pClass = NULL;
    hres = pSvc->GetObject(ClassName, 0, NULL, &pClass, NULL);

    IWbemClassObject* pInParamsDefinition = NULL;
    hres = pClass->GetMethod(MethodName, 0, 
        &pInParamsDefinition, NULL);

    IWbemClassObject* pClassInstance = NULL;
    hres = pInParamsDefinition->SpawnInstance(0, &pClassInstance);

    // Create the values for the in parameters
    VARIANT varCommand;
    varCommand.vt = VT_BSTR;
    varCommand.bstrVal = _bstr_t(L"notepad.exe");

    // Store the value for the in parameters
    hres = pClassInstance->Put(L"CommandLine", 0,
        &varCommand, 0);
    wprintf(L"The command is: %s\n", V_BSTR(&varCommand));

    // Execute Method
    IWbemClassObject* pOutParams = NULL;
    hres = pSvc->ExecMethod(ClassName, MethodName, 0,
    NULL, pClassInstance, &pOutParams, NULL);

    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        cout << "Could not execute method. Error code = 0x" 
             << hex << hres << endl;
        VariantClear(&varCommand);
        SysFreeString(ClassName);
        SysFreeString(MethodName);
        pClass->Release();
        pClassInstance->Release();
        pInParamsDefinition->Release();
        pOutParams->Release();
        pSvc->Release();
        pLoc->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;               // Program has failed.
    }

    // To see what the method returned,
    // use the following code.  The return value will
    // be in &varReturnValue
    VARIANT varReturnValue;
    hres = pOutParams->Get(_bstr_t(L"ReturnValue"), 0, 
        &varReturnValue, NULL, 0);


    // Clean up
    //--------------------------
    VariantClear(&varCommand);
    VariantClear(&varReturnValue);
    SysFreeString(ClassName);
    SysFreeString(MethodName);
    pClass->Release();
    pClassInstance->Release();
    pInParamsDefinition->Release();
    pOutParams->Release();
    pLoc->Release();
    pSvc->Release();
    CoUninitialize();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне представляется, что тут из 4 аргументов [метода `Create`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/CIMWin32Prov/create-method-in-class-win32-process) указывается только первый. А вам надо еще указать в качестве `ProcessStartupInformation` [экземпляр `Win32_ProcessStartup`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/CIMWin32Prov/win32-processstartup)

кусок [примера](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/24253879-711e-4e98-af13-e06430f4fe44/hao-to-use-win32processstartup-method-parameter-in-vc-wmi):

```
//Query the Win32_ProcessStartup Class
IWbemClassObject* pClass_ProcessStartup = NULL;
hres = pSvc->GetObject(L"Win32_ProcessStartup", 0, NULL, &pClass_ProcessStartup, NULL);

//Create a Instance of Win32_ProcessStartup
IWbemClassObject* pClassInstance_ProcessStartup = NULL;
hres = pClass_ProcessStartup->SpawnInstance(0, &pClassInstance_ProcessStartup);

// Create a command to set WinstationDesktop value to empty
//the process does not inherit the desktop and window station of its parent process
VARIANT varCommand_WinstationDesktop;
varCommand_WinstationDesktop.vt = VT_BSTR; 
varCommand_WinstationDesktop .bstrVal = L"ABC";
hres = pClassInstance_ProcessStartup->Put(L"WinstationDesktop",0,&varCommand_WinstationDesktop ,0);

 // Create a command to set ShowWindow value to SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED

VARIANT varCommand_ShowWindow;
varCommand_ShowWindow.vt = VT_UI1;
varCommand_ShowWindow.bVal = SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED;
hres = pClassInstance_ProcessStartup->Put(L"ShowWindow",0,&varCommand_ShowWindow,0);

// Create a command to set ProcessStartupInformation to be the instance of Win32_ProcessStartup  
VARIANT varCommand_ProcessStartup;
varCommand_ProcessStartup.vt = VT_UNKNOWN;
varCommand_ProcessStartup.punkVal = pClassInstance_ProcessStartup;
//set the value to the instance of Win32_Process process
hres =  pClassInstance->Put(L"ProcessStartupInformation", 0, &varCommand_ProcessStartup, 0);
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но я и сам понимаю что нужно сделать. Вопрос в том как это сделать?

Comment: @АлексейМануйлов Добавил пример

Comment: то что нужно. спасибо!